# Click the follow button on Github using Python grab framework

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to follow someone using the python `grab` framework but I can't figure out how to click the follow button. The code that I have so far sends a post request `https://github.com/users/follow?target={username}` but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
user_url = "http://github.com/{username}"
g.go(user_url)
g.setup(method="post")

g.request(url="https://github.com/users/follow?target={username}", post={'target': '{username}'})

g.doc.save('x.html')
```

Comment: are you logging in to github in your python code?

Comment: Yeah, I am logged in. I just can't figure out how to hit the follow button